# Assigning strong passwords to users

Tags: security, passwords

Passwords have lots of downsides but they remain the only technically straightforward way of giving some authentication to users.

Lets talk hypothetically about an education-type system.  Lots of people with passwords, lots of people forgetting their password regularly, lots of CS students and others trying to brute others passwords actually, lots of internal phishing trips and such.

As the admin, *not* knowing the password will not 'keep you out' of the account anyway, so what's the downside of just assigning people random-junk passwords and not enforcing them to change them?

Just giving people strong passwords on slips of paper telling them to keep it safe or memorise and eat it..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have two issues:

- Moved your security problem

Your passwords being so strong, and impossible to remember, the security of your system will be pushed onto the fact that the password will be written on a note next to the screen, or saved somewhere obvious on the computers desktop

A more technical problem will be:

- Security of the random number generator you use.

This is a legitimate problem if you are generating passwords automatically, and someone can query you for new passwords as often as they like (by creating new accounts). It is *hard* to solve as well, though you do have some options. Typically you want to get as many sources as possible ([random.org](http://random.org), [hotbits](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/), cryptographically secure in your language), and combine them. But you shouldn't query the online services too much, and you probably won't get enough from them, so you'll need to rely solely on those retrieved from your cryptographically secure process. Which is 'generally' good, but I wouldn't feel too comfortable if I was continually handing this out, on a ask-and-ye-shall-receive basis.

Personally, I don't think [this](http://michaelsilk.blogspot.com/2004/11/article-solution-to-phishing.html) is such a bad idea, in your case (it's an idea I had about 5 years ago now; wow ...). But really think it over before doing it, and read the articles I've linked.

Comment: Its quite the 4chan flavour of the month to break into a web email account and then do a password reset on the target site; would one-time-passwords received out-of-band by email just automate it, and worse leave the user not knowing something has happened (since with the classic attack at least the user can not log in themselves any more)

Comment: The point is that email is generally used as the security bit; if that's no longer working, then there is an underlying issue there. Note that the request needs to be done on the _site_; and then it's received in the email. You may adapt it slightly, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of generating a sentence as a password if you can get away with it with your system.  It's both easy to remember, and has many characters to guess.  This attempts to mitigate the "sticky note problem" while staying fairly complex.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The downside is that it is much more difficult to remeber and you won't always have the slip of paper with you.

Do as they do at my university: run a password cracker and if the password is too weak, require/request that it will be changed.

Although for Gods sake run the cracker on the passwords *before* they are encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work in organizations for which the security is not one of the main concerns. Otherwise a well-defined security policy should be used, which will require both to have strong passwords and change them regularly.

Answer (score 0):

you said:

> lots of CS students and others trying to brute others passwords actually, 
>   lots of internal phishing trips and such.

If this happens, I guess there is something wrong with the infrastructure itself. To try brute force cracking, the attacker has to have access to the password file or do this live trying to get access to the system. The first case should not happen as the password files should not be accessible to anyone. The second one seems to be easy to counter - just limit the number of login attempts / slow down the rate of logins and of course do some auditing who tries such things.

Assigning predefined passwords does not seem to be a good idea - many people have their own ways of memorizing/creating passwords and if you force them to use something they don't like, they are more likely to write it down somewhere or just loose that piece of paper they've got.

I think the only advice is to develop an efficient scheme for dealing with forgotten passwords. If we assume some kind of educational institution, there may be other forms of authentication that can be used when the user requests to reset his/her forgotten password and the whole process can be made reasonably efficient.